# How to embed an plot in a worksheet in Excel 2003 using Python

Tags: python, excel, excel-2003, vba

I have the following function doing what I want it to do, except that instead of generating the chart on a new worksheet I would like to embed it in the worksheet where the data is written. Also, how can I remove the legend? Here is what I've got:

```
def Get_IV_Data(current_file):

    xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    xlApp.Visible = True

    xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()

    xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets(1)
    xlSheet.Name = filename

    for i in range(0, 10):
        fluff = current_file.readline()

    Input_Parameters = fluff.split("\t")

    from operator import itemgetter
    Cal_Std_V = float(itemgetter(2)(Input_Parameters))

    xlSheet.Cells(1,1).Value = "V"
    xlSheet.Cells(1,2).Value = "I"
    xlSheet.Cells(1,3).Value = "P"

    output_line = 2

    # Assign the data to lists

    for line in current_file:
        try:
            a = line.split("\t")
            STD1, STD2, STD3, V, I, Vcorr, Icorr, v1, v2, v3 = a
            I = round(float(I) * (Cal_Std_V / float(STD1)), 6)
            P = round(float(V) * I, 3)
            xlSheet.Cells(output_line, 1).Value = V
            xlSheet.Cells(output_line, 2).Value = I
            xlSheet.Cells(output_line, 3).Value = P
            output_line += 1

        except ValueError:
            pass

    chart = xlApp.Charts.Add()
    chart.Name= "Plot "+xlSheet.Name
    series = chart.SeriesCollection(1)
    series.XValues= xlSheet.Range("A2:A200")
    series.Values= xlSheet.Range("B2:B200")
    series.Name= filename
```

Comment: Record a macro in excel that does exactly what you want.  Then use the generated code as a guide for how to do it with the COM object.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski, Is there a way to translate the macro code into python, or do I have to figure that out by trial and error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the location of a `Chart` by calling its `Location` method, which takes two parameters.

The first is called `Where`, which takes an enumeration with names `xlLocationAsNewSheet`, `xlLocationAsObject`, and `xlLocationAutomatic` having values of 1, 2, and 3 respectively.

The second parameter is `Name`, which is a worksheet name.

Here is that in Python:

```
xlLocation = {"AsNewSheet": 1,
              "AsObject": 2,
              "Automatic": 3 }
chart.Location(xlLocation["AsObject"], xlSheet.Name)
```

If you prefer magic numbers you can change that to

```
chart.Location(2, xlSheet.Name)
```

Comment: This gave me an error. I think AddChart is new to MS Excel 2007 and won't work for 2003?

Comment: You are correct.  This was for Excel 2007.  Now that I've had time to muck about more, I've completely revised my answer.

Comment: hmmm, that looked promising but it's alleging that the "shapes" object has no attribute "AddChart". I'm starting to think this can't be done in MS 2003.

Comment: @Ben:  I no longer use the shapes object in the above answer.  Continue to create the chart as you have (`chart = xlApp.Charts.Add()`) but after you have created the chart, call the `chart.Location` method to set the location.

Comment: That got it. Thanks! You just saved my sanity.